# How to get all installed printers list and their supported paper size in UWP app?

Tags: c#, printing, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing a UWP app in which i need to print which can be printed in only 3 sizes. To achieve this first i think i need to get the list of all installed printers in the machine and what paper size they support.

I have researched a lot and found out that i could use PrintHelper class which is provided in the printing sample of UWP samples master.

**ShowPrintUIAsync()** that's the method which is showing a drop down of installed printer but however i am not able to find out by debugging that how is it getting all the printers name.

```
 protected virtual void CreatePrintPreviewPages(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the cache of preview pages
        printPreviewPages.Clear();

        // Clear the print canvas of preview pages
        PrintCanvas.Children.Clear();

        // This variable keeps track of the last RichTextBlockOverflow element that was added to a page which will be printed
        RichTextBlockOverflow lastRTBOOnPage;

        // Get the PrintTaskOptions
        PrintTaskOptions printingOptions = ((PrintTaskOptions)e.PrintTaskOptions);

        // Get the page description to deterimine how big the page is
        PrintPageDescription pageDescription = printingOptions.GetPageDescription(0);

        // We know there is at least one page to be printed. passing null as the first parameter to
        // AddOnePrintPreviewPage tells the function to add the first page.
        lastRTBOOnPage = AddOnePrintPreviewPage(null, pageDescription);

        // We know there are more pages to be added as long as the last RichTextBoxOverflow added to a print preview
        // page has extra content
        //while (lastRTBOOnPage.HasOverflowContent && lastRTBOOnPage.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible)
        //{
        //    lastRTBOOnPage = AddOnePrintPreviewPage(lastRTBOOnPage, pageDescription);
        //}

        if (PreviewPagesCreated != null)
        {
            PreviewPagesCreated.Invoke(printPreviewPages, null);
        }

        PrintDocument printDoc = (PrintDocument)sender;

        // Report the number of preview pages created
        printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(printPreviewPages.Count, PreviewPageCountType.Intermediate);
    }
```

I debugged this method also and in the page description i got width and height of the paper but i can't simply assume that it is correct and i need paper size for all printers not for a particular one so this can't be the solution.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For "which can be printed in only 3 sizes", did you mean you want  to restrict the print size in 3 kinds? Did you just want the UWP app can set this for printers or you want to when print the UWP app UI, the paper sizes only have three options to choose?

Comment: Yes @SunteenWu-MSFT. The UI can be printed only in 3 sizes so i need to check first that whatever the printers have installed in the machine whether they support any of the size or not, that is why i wanted to check the printer supported size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of research and debugging i found out that answer was there in my question itself.
In the method mentioned in my question there are these 2 lines

```
 PrintTaskOptions printingOptions = ((PrintTaskOptions)e.PrintTaskOptions);

    // Get the page description to deterimine how big the page is
    PrintPageDescription pageDescription = printingOptions.GetPageDescription(0);
```

In the page description, you get 4 things:
1. Dpix
2.Dpiy
3.Imageable Rect
4.Page size

From these things we would be able to know what paper size printer supports and then proceed according to that.

For the other half of the question: Getting the installed printers list from the local machine, answer is of only one line

```
 private DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection;
 deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync("System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{0ecef634-6ef0-472a-8085-5ad023ecbccd}\"");
```

Now i am able to print from my label printer in CPCL emulation mode.

Happy coding.